# Policyd-spf: Exact Conditions to cause these reject messages?

Tags: postfix, policyd

I can not find any documentation on what each reject messages means. I assume `...domain owner discourages use of this host` happens when `helo.spammer.com` sends an email with `user@example.com` in the from field and example.com has an SPF record that does not include spammer.com

Then what conditions generate `...SPF fail - not authorized`? Wouldn't an not authorized sender be the same condition as the first example?

While im at it, anyone know which conditions return `...access neither permitted nor denied`

If it matters, i have the config as such

```
HELO_reject = SPF_Not_Pass
Mail_From_reject = SPF_Not_Pass
```

And if its helpful, a real case example:

```
SMTPD: connect from ns1.monofe.com[185.21.207.22]
SMTPD: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from ns1.monofe.com[185.21.207.22]: 550 5.7.23 <user@redacted.com>: Recipient address rejected: SPF rejected because SPF fail - not authorized; from=<karen@interfacefm.com> to=<user@redacted.com> proto=ESMTP helo=<ns1.monofe.com>
SMTPD: disconnect from ns1.monofe.com[185.21.207.22] ehlo=2 starttls=1 mail=1 rcpt=0/1 data=0/1 quit=1 commands=5/7
```

and

```
SMTPD: connect from mx47246.payrollloan.info[50.30.47.246]
SMTPD: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from mx47246.payrollloan.info[50.30.47.246]: 550 5.7.23 <user@redacted.com>: Recipient address rejected: SPF rejected because access neither permitted nor denied; from=<bounce-user=redacted.com-user=redacted.com@n95nioshmask.us> to=<user@redacted.com> proto=ESMTP helo=<mx47246.payrollloan.info>
SMTPD: disconnect from mx47246.payrollloan.info[50.30.47.246] ehlo=2 starttls=1 mail=1 rcpt=0/1 quit=1 commands=5/6
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result of an SPF policy evaluation is not a simple `pass`/`fail`; there are [five distinct non-error results, plus `temperror` and `permerror`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7208#section-2.6). The different results you're seeing are the software translating these distinct results into human-friendly explanations.

Your first example is for `interfacefm.com`; if we review its SPF record it currently looks like this:

```
"v=spf1 +a +a:ns1.c57578.sgvps.net include:_spf.mailspamprotection.com -all"
```

The `-all` at the end will return a `fail` result if a host does not match another mechanism in the record.

Your second example is `n95nioshmask.us`, and the record is:

```
"v=spf1 mx a ptr include:spf.improvmx.com ?all"
```

`?all` specifies a `neutral` result.

The full list of qualifiers is:

```
      "+" pass
      "-" fail
      "~" softfail
      "?" neutral
```

You didn't provide an example for "discourages use of this host", but it's probably a domain with `softfail` as the default result.